# Kotlin - Firebase and Glide - get image url so glide can use it

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage, android-glide

I'm having a hard time getting an image URL from firebase storage, I got the photo URL from the database, but as I know, Glide can't get a picture from the link like this: com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask@62873ce

Here are my Storage and database references:

```
 private fun StorageReference.uploadUserPhoto(uid: String, photo: Uri,
                                             onSuccess: (UploadTask.TaskSnapshot) -> Unit) {
    child("users/$uid/photo").putFile(mImageUri).addOnCompleteListener {
        if (it.isSuccessful) {
            mStorage.child("users/$uid/photo").downloadUrl.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    onSuccess(it.result!!)
                } else {
                    showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


private fun DatabaseReference.updateUserPhoto(uid: String, photoUrl: String,
                                              onSuccess: () -> Unit){
    child("users/$uid/photo").setValue(photoUrl)
        .addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                onSuccess()
            } else {
                showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
            }
        }
}
```

here is the function:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        val uid = mAuth.currentUser!!.uid
        mStorage.uploadUserPhoto(uid, mImageUri) {
            val photoUrl = it.task.toString()
            mDatabase.updateUserPhoto(uid, photoUrl) {
                mUser = mUser.copy(photo = photoUrl)
                profile_image.loadUserPhoto(mUser.photo)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried changing

```
val photoUrl = it.task.toString()
```

to

```
val photoUrl = it.downloadUrl.toString()
```

but it highlights 'downloadUrl' as unresolved reference

Full code:

```
    package com.example.homeactivity.activities

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.text.Editable
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider
import com.example.homeactivity.R
import com.example.homeactivity.models.User
import com.example.homeactivity.views.PasswordDialog
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential
import com.google.firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_edit_profile.*
import java.io.File
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*


class EditProfileActivity : AppCompatActivity(), PasswordDialog.Listener {

    private lateinit var mImageUri: Uri
    private lateinit var mStorage: StorageReference
    private val TAG = "EditProfileActivity"
    private lateinit var mUser: com.example.homeactivity.models.User
    private lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var mDatabase: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var mPendingUser: com.example.homeactivity.models.User
    private val TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE = 1
    val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US)


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile)
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate")

        close_image.setOnClickListener { finish() }
        save_image.setOnClickListener { updateProfile() }
        change_photo_text.setOnClickListener { takeCameraPicture() }

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference

        mDatabase.child("users").child(mAuth.currentUser!!.uid)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(ValueEventListenerAdapter {
                mUser = it.getValue(com.example.homeactivity.models.User::class.java)!!
                name_input.setText(mUser.name, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
                username_input.setText(mUser.username, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
                website_input.setText(mUser.website, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
                bio_input.setText(mUser.bio, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
                email_input.setText(mUser.email, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
                phone_input.setText(mUser.phone?.toString(), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
                profile_image.loadUserPhoto(mUser.photo)
            })
    }

    private fun takeCameraPicture() {
        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
            val imageFile = createImageFile()
            mImageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                this,
                "com.example.homeactivity.fileprovider",
                imageFile
            )
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageUri)
            startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE)
        }
    }

    private fun createImageFile(): File {
        val storageDir: File? = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        return File.createTempFile(
            "JPEG_${simpleDateFormat.format(Date())}_",
            ".jpg",
            storageDir
        )
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val uid = mAuth.currentUser!!.uid
            mStorage.uploadUserPhoto(uid, mImageUri) {
                val photoUrl = it.task.toString()
                mDatabase.updateUserPhoto(uid, photoUrl) {
                    mUser = mUser.copy(photo = photoUrl)
                    profile_image.loadUserPhoto(mUser.photo)
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private fun updateProfile() {
        mPendingUser = readInputs()
        val error = validate(mPendingUser)
        if (error == null) {
            if (mPendingUser.email == mUser.email) {
                updateUser(mPendingUser)
            } else {
                PasswordDialog().show(supportFragmentManager, "password_dialog")
            }
        } else {
            showToast(error)
        }
    }


    private fun readInputs(): User {
        return User(
            name = name_input.text.toString(),
            username = username_input.text.toString(),
            email = email_input.text.toString(),
            website = website_input.text.toStringOrNull(),
            bio = bio_input.text.toStringOrNull(),
            phone = phone_input.text.toStringOrNull()
        )
    }

    override fun onPasswordConfirm(password: String) {
        if (password.isNotEmpty()) {
            val credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(mUser.email, password)
            mAuth.currentUser!!.reauthenticate(credential) {
                mAuth.currentUser!!.updateEmail(mPendingUser.email) {
                    updateUser(mPendingUser)
                }
            }
        } else {
            showToast("You must enter your password")
        }
    }

    private fun updateUser(user: com.example.homeactivity.models.User) {
        val updatesMap = mutableMapOf<String, Any?>()
        if (user.name != mUser.name) updatesMap["name"] = user.name
        if (user.username != mUser.username) updatesMap["username"] = user.username
        if (user.website != mUser.website) updatesMap["website"] = user.website
        if (user.bio != mUser.bio) updatesMap["bio"] = user.bio
        if (user.email != mUser.email) updatesMap["email"] = user.email
        if (user.phone != mUser.phone) updatesMap["phone"] = user.phone

        mDatabase.updateUser(mAuth.currentUser!!.uid, updatesMap) {
            showToast("Profile saved")
            finish()
        }
    }

    private fun validate(user: com.example.homeactivity.models.User): String? =
        when {
            user.name.isEmpty() -> "Please enter name"
            user.username.isEmpty() -> "Please enter username"
            user.email.isEmpty() -> "Please enter email"
            else -> null
        }

    private fun FirebaseUser.updateEmail(email: String, onSuccess: () -> Unit) {
        updateEmail(email).addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                onSuccess()
            } else {
                showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun StorageReference.uploadUserPhoto(uid: String, photo: Uri,
                                                 onSuccess: (UploadTask.TaskSnapshot) -> Unit) {
        child("users/$uid/photo").putFile(mImageUri).addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                mStorage.child("users/$uid/photo").downloadUrl.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (it.isSuccessful) {
                        onSuccess(it.result!!)
                    } else {
                        showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private fun DatabaseReference.updateUserPhoto(uid: String, photoUrl: String,
                                                  onSuccess: () -> Unit){
        child("users/$uid/photo").setValue(photoUrl)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    onSuccess()
                } else {
                    showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
                }
            }
    }

    private fun DatabaseReference.updateUser(
        uid: String, updates: Map<String, Any?>,
        onSuccess: () -> Unit
    ) {
        child("users").child(uid).updateChildren(updates)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    onSuccess()
                } else {
                    showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
                }
            }
    }

    private fun FirebaseUser.reauthenticate(credential: AuthCredential, onSuccess: () -> Unit) {
        reauthenticate(credential).addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                onSuccess()
            } else {
                showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your uploadUserPhoto method like this

```
    private fun StorageReference.uploadUserPhoto(uid: String, photo: Uri,
                                             onSuccess: (String) -> Unit) {
    val uTask = mStorage.child("users/$uid/photo").putFile(mImageUri)
    child("users/$uid/photo").putFile(mImageUri).addOnCompleteListener {
        if (it.isSuccessful) {
            uTask.continueWithTask { task ->
                mStorage.child("users/$uid/photo").downloadUrl
            }.addOnCompleteListener{
               if (it.isSuccessful && it.result != null) {
                    onSuccess(it.result!!.toString)
                } else {
                    showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your onActivityResult use url like

```
 val photoUrl = it
```

Comment: for "onSuccess(it.result!!)" It gives me Type Mismatch - Required Uploadtask.TaskSnapshot?   Found: Uri?

Comment: but I am sure it should be Uri however, don't know where I made a mistake...

Comment: @RenatoLulic check my edited answer. It didn't run this code if you get any syntax error, let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot man!! It works now :)) I was struggling for days with that. I really appreciate it!